# Creating new Stat with survival::survfit object failing (NA removed from data in compute_group)

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival

I want to create a new stat which calculates interval-censored survival with `survival::survfit.formula`. But I seem to get a wrong data frame in the `compute_group` function, and I struggle to find the reason for it.

Creating a data frame with exactly the same code "outside" and using geom_path (which I want to use for the stat), results in a fine result (see expected result). - it seems as if `survfit.formula()` is creating  NAs within `compute_group()`, but I don't understand why.

setting /adding `na.rm = TRUE/FALSE` does not change anything.

Also using `Inf` instead of NA for time2 does not help.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(survival)
set.seed(42)
testdf <- data.frame(time = sample(30, replace = TRUE), time2 = c(20, 10, 10, 30, rep(NA, 26)))

fit_icens <-
  survival::survfit.formula(
    survival::Surv(time = time, time2 = time2, type = "interval2") ~ 1,
    data = testdf
  )
```

**Expected result**

```
path <- data.frame(time = fit_icens$time, time2= fit_icens$surv)

ggplot(path, aes(x = time, y = time2)) +
  geom_path() +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 1))
```

[image]

**Failing**

```r
StatIcen <- ggplot2::ggproto("StatIcen", Stat,
  required_aes = c("time", "time2"),
  compute_group = function(data, scales) {
    fit_icens <-
      survival::survfit.formula(
        survival::Surv(time = data$time, time2 = data$time2, type = "interval2") ~ 1,
        data = data
      )
    path <- data.frame(x = fit_icens$time, y = fit_icens$surv)
    path
  }
)

stat_icen <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "path",
                      position = "identity", show.legend = NA,
                      inherit.aes = TRUE, ...) {
  layer(
    stat = StatIcen, data = data, mapping = mapping, geom = geom,
    position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(...)
  )
}

ggplot(testdf, aes(time = time, time2 = time2)) +
  stat_icen()
#> Warning: Removed 26 rows containing non-finite values (stat_icen).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question Tjebo, thanks for posting.

As you have already figured out, the problem is that the `NA` values are being stripped out of your data before it is passed to `compute_group`. The *Extending ggplot* vignette doesn't mention this, but your data is first passed through the `compute_layer` member function of your ggproto object. Since you haven't defined a `compute_layer` method, your `StatIcen` class inherits the method from the class `ggplot2::Stat`.

If you look at the source code for this method in `ggplot2::Stat$compute_layer`, you will see this is where your `NA` values are stripped out, using the `remove_missing` function, which removes rows in your data frame with missing values in any of the named columns. Presumably, you still want `NA` values removed if they appear in your `time` column, but not if they appear in `time2`.

So all I have done here is to copy the source code from `Stat$compute_layer` and adjust the `remove_missing` call slightly, then make it a member of `StatIcen`:

```r
StatIcen <- ggplot2::ggproto("StatIcen", Stat,
  required_aes = c("time", "time2"),
  compute_group = function(data, scales){
    fit_icens <- survival::survfit.formula(
      survival::Surv(time = data$time,  time2 = data$time2, 
                     type = "interval2") ~ 1, data = data)
    data.frame(x = fit_icens$time, y = fit_icens$surv)
  },
  compute_layer = function (self, data, params, layout) 
  {
    ggplot2:::check_required_aesthetics(self$required_aes, c(names(data), 
        names(params)), snake_class(self))
    data <- remove_missing(data, params$na.rm, "time", 
                           ggplot2:::snake_class(self), finite = TRUE)
    params <- params[intersect(names(params), self$parameters())]
    args <- c(list(data = quote(data), scales = quote(scales)), params)
    ggplot2:::dapply(data, "PANEL", function(data) {
        scales <- layout$get_scales(data$PANEL[1])
        tryCatch(do.call(self$compute_panel, args), 
                 error = function(e) {
            warning("Computation failed in `", 
                    ggplot2:::snake_class(self), 
                    "()`:\n", e$message, call. = FALSE)
            ggplot2:::new_data_frame()
        })
    })
  }
)
```

So now we get:

```r
ggplot(testdf, aes(time = time, time2 = time2)) + stat_icen()
```

[image]

Comment: that is brilliant. Gosh, impressed you figured that one out.